# When to use getXXAttribute vs a relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am putting together a model of mine and I am wondering what is the most relevent method to use for something like "author".

I have:

```
public function images() {
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Image', 'imageable');
}

public function ratings() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Rating');
}

public function favorited() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Favorite');
}

public function author() {
    return $this->hasOne('User');
}

public function getMyFavoriteAttribute() {
    return $this->favorited->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count();
}

public function getFavoritesAttribute() {
    return $this->favorited->count();
}

public function getRatingAttribute() {
    return $this->ratings->sum('rating');
}
```

I have created a relationship called author as seen above. When would it be preferred to create this as a getAuthorAttribute?

Answer (score 1):

`get__Attribute` is only necessary if you want to manipulate the original value of the stored attribute. Due to the fact that `Author` is already accessible through your relation it's not necessary to add an additional getter.

Comment: Would it make more sense to create a getAttribute in the user model called getNameAttribute that concatenates first_name and last_name and access vie $product->author->name ?

Comment: Yes, that's totally fine. If you have a lot of this concatenation and string formatting stuff you could/should take a look at the ViewModel approach to keep your DTO's clean.